# Android Math Calculation Not Giving Expected Value

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run a calculation but I'm not getting the correct result and struggling to understand why.

**Calculation**

```
float Signal = ((20 - 0) / (20 - 4)) * (F5 - 4) + 0;
```

`F5` = 12 and is declared as a "Float" type

When run through a calculator, you end up with the following:

1. ((20 - 0) / (20 - 4)) * (12 - 4) + 0
2. ((20) / (16)) * (12 - 4) + 0
3. (1.25) * (8) + 0
4. Result = 10

However, when this is run through the Android code, I get the result of 8.

Why is this, I'd like to understand what's going on

Comment: What is the declared type of `F5`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Updated, its a float type

Comment: 20/16 is still an integer division. You are expecting 1.25 and you will get 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term `((20 - 0) / (20 - 4))` is calculated using integer arithmetic, giving a value of `1`.  This makes the final result `8` regardless of the type of `F5`.  If you want it to happen in floating point, use floating point constants

```
float Signal = ((20f - 0f) / (20f - 4f)) * (F5 - 4f) + 0f;
```

Technically you don't need all the constants to be floats due to numeric promotion, but it is much clearer to those reading your code that you *intended* for everything to be a float.

Comment: Well there you go! Thanks for the learning curve there. (i'll accept as the answer when SO lets me)

Comment: You can make it easier on yourself in the future: `20F - 0F` for example.